# Replacing NaN with random variables that keep the standard deviation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I have a matrix `A` as a row vector containing some missing values `NaN`. Let's assume it looks like the following:

```
A = [2; NaN; 0.3; NaN; -0.8; NaN; 1; -0.5; NaN; 0.2];
```

The series has a `A_mean = nanmean(A, 1)` of `0.37` and a `A_std = nanstd(A, 1)` of `0.93`.

I created a random vector `B` of the same size in

```
B = rand(1, 10)';
```

I defined an upper bound `ub` and a lower bound `lb` as

```
ub = A_mean * 5;
lb = A_mean * (-5);
```

So I changed `B` to

```
B = ub + (lb-ub) * rand(1, 10);
```

I can replace all `NaN` values in `A` by

```
idx = isnan(A);
A(idx) = B(idx);
```

Taking `A_std = nanstd(A, 1)` of this new defined vector leads to `std`, which is randomly different to `0.93`.

I would like to know, whether I can replace the missing values `NaN` in `A` with random variables and keep the std the same?

Answer (score 1):

If your data coming from a uniform distribution `U(0,1)`, it can be logical to replace `nan` with a random number.

If your data distribution is different from `U(0,1)`, the replacement can be counted as uniform error in your data.

Hence, if your random number has the same distribution with your data, you can do it easily, and if not, it can be counted as an error in your data.